# Placing dijit.form.Select dropdown at a specific place instead of body's bottom

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

Does anybody know how to place dijit.form.Select dropdown in some div but not at the bottom of body as dijit does? I have replaced select element inside a dijit.Dialog - the select is ok, but it has no options. All options are at the bottom of body, behind dialog's underlay. tried MySelect.dropDown.placeAt() - it has strange affect, it places some empty div with scrollbar but values are anyway on the same place and I'm unable to access their div - it's unable to use MySelect.dropDown.parentWidget because it points to MySelect.

Comment: Also I found that I won't be able to place dropdown inside a dialog anyway because I have there are lots of divs which require overflow:hidden. So leaving dropdown inside body is normal for me - I can set position:absolute at least and play with it. But how to get it out of dialog's underlay? z-index is not working.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, z-index is working, it's ok. But anyway the question about moving dropdown container into another place in dom is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via the 'dropDown' property of your widget.

```
var node = dijit.byId('myselect').dropDown.domNode
```

This will give you the first child of the global menu-popup-container. There is one only, since the layout of menus in dijit is made so, that only one should be present at same time.

So

```
   node.className == "dijitSelectMenu" 
&& node.parentNode.className == "dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup"
```

The one with a z-index, is the dijitPopup (which is global and changing style here would change for any other select box and perhaps even tooltip you use as well)